# createPages in Gatsby issues ; duplications and unrendered content

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, headless-cms

I've had a few errors trying to render single blog posts.

I tried using the page template with /post/{post_name} and I was getting this error:

*warn Non-deterministic routing danger: Attempting to create page: "/blog/", but
page "/blog" already exists
This could lead to non-deterministic routing behavior*

I tried again with /blog/{post_name}.

I now have both routes, which I'm not sure how to clean up; but more importantly, on those pages, nothing renders, even though there should be an h1 with it's innerhtml set to the node.title and likewise a div for the content.

I've uploaded my config and components to https://github.com/zackrosegithub/gatsby so you can have a look.

Not sure how to fix

I just want to see my content rendered on the screen.

Developer tools don't seem to help when there's no content rendered as I can't find anything to inspect to try to access it another way.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should post errors which might have occured on gatsby build. Checking your whole project on github is a bit much to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is partially correct. You are using a promise-based approach but when using `then()` you are already settling and partially resolving it so you don't need to use the callback of [`resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which may be causing a duplication of the promise function so try removing it.

Additionally, you may want to use a more friendly approach using `async`/`await` functions. Something like:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const yourQuery= await graphql(
          `
            {
              allWordpressPost {
                edges{
                  node{
                    id
                    title
                    slug
                    excerpt
                    content
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `
  if (yourQuery.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`);

    return;
  }
  

          const postTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/post.js")
          _.each(yourQuery.data.allWordpressPost.edges, edge => {
            createPage({
              path: `/post/${edge.node.slug}/`,
              component: slash(postTemplate),
              context: edge.node,
            })
          })
        })

 // and so on for the rest of the queries

};
```

In addition, place a `console.log(pageContext)` in your `postTemplate` to get what's reaching that point and name the template as:

```
const Post = ({pageContext}) => {
 console.log("your pageContext is", pageContext); 
return  <div>
        <h1>
            {pageContext.title}
        </h1>
    </div>
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: fantastic, that console.log is really handy as well :) thankyou

Comment: This question is completely outside of the boundaries of this topic and extremely broad

Comment: If the issue has been solved, please consider accepting/upvote the answer to close the topic

Comment: No worries; haven’t had a chance to re-write yet was going to wait until I had tested it as currently content isn’t rendering yet