# warn Non-deterministic routing danger: Attempting to create page: [...] already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I finished writing a small blog application using `Gatsby` and `React`.
Everything works fine when I try it locally. So I proceed with `gatsby build` and deploy the build folder into `Netlify`. However, after the deployment, the content of some of the pages is not shown despite locally everything works fine.

**Description of the problem**: I have a navbar with "Home", "Healthcare", "Technology", "Robotics", "Posts", "NewsLetter", and every time a user clicks on for example "Robotics" a series of posts from that category is shown.
Now locally everything works fine but as soon as I deploy I can only see "Posts" page which carries all the posts. The other choices from the navbar are not rendering the other posts categories.

Below the error I am getting from the terminal:

`warn Non-deterministic routing danger: Attempting to create page: "/healthcare/", but page "/healthcare" already exists This could lead to non-deterministic routing behavior`

`warn Non-deterministic routing danger: Attempting to create page: "/robotics/", but page "/robotics" already exists This could lead to non-deterministic routing behavior`

`warn Non-deterministic routing danger: Attempting to create page: "/technology/", but page "/technology" already exists This could lead to non-deterministic routing behavior`

This leads me to think that some pages are not rendered at the proper time, however, this does not explain the difference between localhost perfectly working and the deployed version not working properly.

Below my **gatsby-node.js**

```
const path = require('path')
// create pages dynamically
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
 // from actions we can destructure createPage
  const { createPage } = actions
   // below we will be running two queries at the same time 
   // instead of one query only
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMdx {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
      category: allMdx {
        distinct(field: frontmatter___category)
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allMdx.nodes.forEach(({ frontmatter: { slug } }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/posts/${slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/post-template.js`),
      context: {
        slug,
      },
    })
  })
  result.data.category.distinct.forEach(category => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${category}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/category-template.js`),
      context: {
        category,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Below is also the file **post-template.js**

```
const PostTemplate = ({data}) => {
  const {
    mdx: {
      frontmatter: {title, category, image, date}, 
      body,},
    } = data;

  return ( 
  <Layout>
    <Hero/>
    <Wrapper>
      {/* post info */}
      <article>
        <Image fluid={image.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        <div className="post-info">
          <span>{category}</span>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p>{date}</p>
          <div className="underline"></div>
        </div>
        <MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
      </article>
      {/* banner */}
      <article>
        <Banner/>
      </article>
    </Wrapper>
  </Layout>
  )
}


export const query = graphql`
  query GetSinglePost($slug: String) {
    mdx(frontmatter: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        category
        date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
      body
    }
  }
`
const Wrapper = styled.section`
// style goes here ...
`

export default PostTemplate
```

and the file **category-template.js**

```
const CategoryTemplate = props => {
  console.log(props);
  const {
    pageContext: { category },
  } = props;

  const {
    data: {
      categories: {nodes:posts}
    }
  } = props;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Hero/>
      <Posts posts={posts} title={`category / ${category}`}/>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query GetCategories($category: String) {
    categories: allMdx(sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}, filter: {frontmatter: {category: {eq: $category}}}) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        frontmatter {
          title
          author
          category
          date(formatString: "MMMM, Do, YYYY")
          slug
          readTime
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
export default CategoryTemplate
```

Below the structure of the `robotics` page component (all the other page components `healthcare` and `technology` have the same exact structure so I am only including one)

**robotics.js**

```
const robotics = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <SEO title="Robotics"/>
            <Hero />
            <h2>robotics page</h2>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default robotics
```

In order to solve this problem I did a lot of research but before I would like to pint out that I already clean and redeploy the same application a couple of times before. So what I tried so far:

1. `sudo gatsby clean && sudo gatsby develop` after it was working I did `sudo gatsby build`

After deploying the build folder some pages were not rendering properly so I:

2. `sudo m -rf node_modules` `sudo rm -rf public/` and `sudo rm -rf package-lock.json`
   and procedeed with:
3. `sudo npm install` (if necessary you have to do `sudo nom install --unsafe-perm`) and
4. `sudo gatsby develop && sudo gatsby build`

But unfortuantely the same exact outcome: localhost everthing works fine and on `Netlify` some pages were not rendering at all.

So I did additional research and I studied [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917497/createpages-in-gatsby-issues-duplications-and-unrendered-content) which represents the same exact problem I have. Unfortunately no answer was accepted. But I tried to apply the suggestion and in fact on my `gatsby-node.js` I had:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const yourQuery= await graphql(
          `
            {
              parameters here
            }
          `
  if (yourQuery.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`);

    return;
  }
```

But nothing happened.

I studied [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15866) and [this too](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/help-page-created-twice%7E14e69e60-8327-42fa-850c-11dc7991ee86). This post says that "MDX pages cant currently be in the same directory as JSX pages" but I am not sure this is accurate and did not see it in the official documentation an example showing not to do that.

Please guide me to a potential solution on this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue relies on the naming, and I assume that it will affect all pages (robotics, healthcare, technology, etc). This:

```
const robotics = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <SEO title="Robotics"/>
            <Hero />
            <h2>robotics page</h2>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default robotics
```

Should be:

```
const Robotics = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <SEO title="Robotics"/>
            <Hero />
            <h2>robotics page</h2>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Robotics
```

Notice the capitalized component (`Robotics`). This is because, in React, all component names must be capitalized otherwise, React's assignation will never work.

The rest of the code, without a CodeSandbox it's difficult to check but it looks good.

In addition, something that can also lead to this behavior is the use of plugins such as [`gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes/), so double-check that if you are using it.

---

Outside the scope of the question (and because of `sudo gatsby develop && sudo gatsby build`) it seems that you don't know the difference between `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build`, they are not complementary and it doesn't make sense to use that command.

To summarize, `gatsby build` creates a version of your site with production-ready optimizations like packaging up your site’s config, data, and code, and creating all the static HTML pages that eventually get [rehydrated](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary#hydration) into a React application.

`gatsby develop` just runs a server in the background, enabling useful features and it is optimized for rapid feedback and extra debugging information. It doesn't bundle and compile your code production environment, potentially hiding some issues that will appear in Netlify, since it runs `gatsby build`.

With that command, you are developing your site and quitting the process by running the `gatsby build`, without serving it.

So, to double-check your site before pushing it to Netlify, I would suggest running a `gatsby build && gatsby serve` locally, since, if the Node versions in Netlify and locally are the same, the project must behave equally in both environments.

You can read the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/) for further explanations.

---

> I did additional research and I studied [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917497/createpages-in-gatsby-issues-duplications-and-unrendered-content) which represents the
> same exact problem I have. Unfortunately no answer was accepted.

I answered that question. The error output may be the same but it's caused but a completely different use-case. In that case, the issue relies on a wrong/unfinished promise approach, and it only affects the dynamic pages, in your case are the opposite. In your scenario, the "static" pages are the problem due to bad naming because React can't resolve the component assignation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and for clarifying the difference between `develop`, `build`, and `serve`. Much clearer now. Everything works as I was hoping to! Thanks for your time!